# Error required a bean of type 'XXX' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm updating a spring boot project by adding a page called news and it has error below.

> Field newsService in com.lrs.admin.controller.NewsController required
> a bean of type 'com.lrs.admin.service.INewsService' that could not be
> found.

The code is like below:
Application.java

```
@MapperScan("com.lrs.admin.dao")
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

NewController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/news")
public class NewsController extends BaseController {
    private final static String qxurl="news/list";
    
    @Autowired
    private INewsService newsService;
```

INewsService.java

```
package com.lrs.admin.service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Componnt;
import com.lrs.admin.util.ParameterMap;

    @Component
    public interface INewsService {
        public List<ParameterMap> list();
        public Map<String,Object> getNews(ParameterMap pm);
        public Map<String,Object> edit(ParameterMap pm); 
        public Map<String,Object> add(ParameterMap pm,HttpSession session); 
        public Map<String,Object> del(String newsId); 
    }
```

NewsService.java

```
public class NewsService implements INewsService {

    @Autowired
    private NewsDao newsDao;
```

NewsDao.java

```
public interface NewsDao {
    public List<ParameterMap> list();
    public List<ParameterMap> getAllNewsById(ParameterMap pm);
    public ParameterMap getNewsById(ParameterMap pm);
    public void updateNews(ParameterMap pm);
    public void addNews(ParameterMap pm);
    public void delNews(String roleId);
//  public void delUserRole(String roleId);
}
```

NewsMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.lrs.admin.dao.NewsDao">

</mapper>
```

I just create those files and not implement any method yet.Is this the reason? Any help?Thx.

Comment: what does the rest of the error message/stacktrace say?

Comment: Normally you use `@Component`, `@Service`, etc. on the implementing classes, not the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never put `@Component` (or `@Service`, ...) at an interface, because this make the interface useless. Let me explain why.

- If you have an interface then you want to use that interface for the injection point type.
- The purpose of an interface is that it define a contract that can been implemented by several implementations. On the other side you have your injection point (`@Autowired`). Having just one interface and only one class that implement it, is useless.

You have to remove `@Component` annotation from `INewsService` and add `@Service` annotaion in `NewsService` class because Spring tries to instantiate it to create a Bean `@Service`, but it's an Interface, so thats not possible.

Answer (score 1):

you should annotate `@Service` on the class which implements the interface instead of the interface itself. That is, annotate the `NewsService` with `@Service`, and you can remove the `@Component` tag from `INewsService`

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this `@Component` from your `INewsService.java` and add `@Service` to `NewsService.java` it will resolve the error and be more comprehensive, cause `@Component` is a generalization of `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller`.

`@Component`  : generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component

`@Repository` : stereotype for persistence layer

`@Service`    : stereotype for service layer

`@Controller` : stereotype for presentation layer (spring-mvc)